# Android Job scheduler behavior when device goes for deep sleep

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I am currently working with an android application that uses android job scheduler to call an api at certain interval(lets say every 4 hours).
Suppose my device is not on charge and there is no activity being done on it, so it goes to sleep after some time(lets say after 1 hour of last api call).
Now my device wakes up after 5 hours due to some activity that I did deleberatly. Will the scheduler call the api immediately(as its more than 4 hrs since last call)? or will it wait for next 3 hours to run the job?
(*I have not acquired the wake lock in this case so the device will go to sleep.)

Answer (score 4):

I think you by Deep Sleep you mean Doze. When your device in doze mode your JobServices will not trigger. Periodic job can't be exact. A job is either exact or periodic. So periodic will trigger while in maintenance window between execution interval. If you running your jobs on Lollipop + with high frequency, then it's possible, that some periods are skipped, because the device is saving battery.

[image]

Check out restrictions for doze mode:

> - Network access is suspended.
> - The system ignores wake locks.
> - Standard AlarmManager alarms (including setExact() and setWindow()) are deferred to the next maintenance window.
> - If you need to set alarms that fire while in Doze, use setAndAllowWhileIdle() or setExactAndAllowWhileIdle().
> - Alarms set with setAlarmClock() continue to fire normally — the system exits Doze shortly before those alarms fire.
> - The system does not perform Wi-Fi scans.
> - The system does not allow sync adapters to run.
> - The system does not allow JobScheduler to run.

But you can use some hacks to make your job executes at specific time/immediately after scheduling.

Comment: Anton, can you suggest a good hacks as you say for executing immediately after scheduling? We've tried using AlarmManager, JobScheduler, WorkManager... none seem to wake up and do our tiny little job during Deep Sleep.

Comment: Anton, can you please mention some hacks that will help to run background tasks during doze mode?